# Does a sequence in a subset of a compact set in a metric space have a convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, compactness

Let $X$ be a metric space and Let $Y\subset X$ be a compact set. Take a set $Z\subset Y$. Consider a sequence $(x_n)\subset Z$. Does $(x_n)$ have a convergent subsequence in $Z$?

I know that (i) in general, a bounded sequence in a metric space does not have a convergent subsequence, and (ii) if $Z$ is closed then it is compact and thus $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence by the sequential compactness. But, I'm not sure in the current situation if there is a convergent subsequence. Clearly $Z$ is bounded, but now I have additional structure that the sequence lives in a subset of a compact set.

Comment: Also, you should clarify for yourself whether by "convergent subsequence" you mean "convergent in the subset" or "convergent in the ambient space". :)

Comment: I meant convergent in the subset $Z$, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question amounts to *"is every subspace of a compact metric space compact?"*

This is not true. Consider for example the compact metric space $X=Y = [0,1]$, the subspace $Z = Y\setminus\{0\}$, and the sequence $(x_n)$ given by $x_n = 1/n$ for all $n\ge1$. Then $(x_n)$ converges in $Y$ (to $0$), but not in $Z$. Any convergent subsequence must also converge to $0$, thus $(x_n)$ does not have a subsequence that converges in $Z$.